# Find what is creating folders on SD card

Tags: file-system

I got two useless folders on /sdcard/ (`baidu` and `baiduMapSDK`) and even though I delete them, they will generate automatically. How can I know which application or which process created these two folders?

Comment: @Leng The only way to know is delete the folder and use app one by one and see each time which app is creating it. If any app is doing so you don't have to worry as its a general rule for that app which need this empty folder to work on.

Answer (score 4):

Baidu is the Chinese competitor of Google. I can't but notice your nickname Leng sounds Chinese as well!

So my bet goes to your phone having Chinese apps, including one related to the Baidu search engine.

These folders are definitely being made by this app.

These folders also might not be empty; content which starts with a `.dotBeforeName` is hidden, and won't show in most file navigators.

My recommendation is to leave those folders be. If you want to get rid of them, you'll also have to uninstall these Baidu apps.

Comment: Rather than being the Chinese version of Google, they're a Chinese **competitor** to Google. [Google China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_China) is the Chinese version of Google.

Comment: Yeah, by version I meant clone. These chinese guys have censored everything and then made clones of it.

Comment: I didn't install any baidu related apps and these two folders are empty. I hate baidu, so I want to get rid of them, but I do not want to uninstall all the apps in my phone to test which app create these two folders.

Comment: Do you have any chinese apps installed?